# How was King Henry VIII able to get syphilis?

Tags: england, new-world, disease, henry-viii

How did King Henry VIII get this disease when syphilis was a disease originating from the Americas?

Comment: related: [Evidence that 16th and 17th century wig craze was started by the Syphilis epidemic?](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/evidence-that-16th-and-17th-century-wig-craze-was-started-by-the-syphilis-epidem)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The currently accepted theory for this [is that he didn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_VIII_of_England#Death_and_succession). Although there is some debate as to what his exact problem was, it doesn't appear to have been Syphilis.

> The theory that Henry suffered from syphilis has been dismissed by
>   most historians. A more recent theory suggests that Henry's
>   medical symptoms are characteristic of untreated Type II
>   diabetes. Alternatively, his wives' pattern of pregnancies and
>   his mental deterioration have led some to suggest that the king may
>   have been Kell positive and suffered from McLeod syndrome.
>   According to another study, Henry VIII's history and body morphology
>   was probably the result of traumatic brain injury after his 1536
>   jousting accident, which in turn led to a neuroendocrine cause of his
>   obesity. This analysis identifies growth hormone deficiency (GHD) as
>   the source for his increased adiposity but also significant
>   behavioural changes noted in his later years, including his multiple
>   marriages.

Answer (score 18):

- Columbus sailed the ocean blue in fourteen hundred and ninety two; a full 55 years before Henry died in 1547. Henry was not known for his chaste ways, so it is quite conceivable that he would have been an early contractor of a new venereal disease.
- The most recent excavations at Pompeii have revealed remains two twin teen-aged sisters, apparently in a brothel, with apparent syphilitic symptoms; if so, the disease may not have originated in the Americas after all:

  - [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-11952322)
  - [and here](http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?410829-Pompeii-skeletons-reveal-secrets-of-Roman-lives-or-do-they)
    among many others easily found by Google.

This remains contentious and unresolved however.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the evidence for a New World origin is far more compelling. However, you are quite correct to point out that this is still an [unsettled issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_syphilis#Origin).

Comment: Left field alternative: Pompeii incidence of Syphilis is due to Phoenician contact with the Americas. (Note: I do not actually hold this theory; I just think it is interesting to consider. One of the strangest things to me is the distribution of Haplogroup R1b and its presence in pre-Columbian America, see [link](http://dnaconsultants.com/_blog/DNA_Consultants_Blog/post/native-americans-have-deep-ancestry-in-europe/)).

Comment: @called2voyage - There are all sorts of fanciful theories you could come up with. Perhaps a gigantic volcanic eruption spread it by physically blasting the virus to the other side of the earth too. But that quickly gets to be a mess, so we need some kind of razor to cut through it all. I prefer [Occam's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), which I'm afraid leaves difficult to explain things like inter-continental ballistic viri or demigod-like Phonecians tireme sailors on the cutting-room floor.

Comment: @T.E.D. I understand that Occam's razor currently puts Phoenician contact with the Americas on thin ice, but I don't understand why they would have to be demigod-like. Philip Beale recreated a hypothetical Phoenician voyage to circumnavigate Africa to prove it would be possible and he believes it is possible to cross the Atlantic this way--he is going to attempt this voyage as well.

Comment: @called2voyage - I wonder if I could get funding and noteriety for my ICBV idea too then...

Comment: @T.E.D. Possibly from North Korea.